# Two identical methods with different parameter types

Tags: java, generics

I have two nearly identical methods in Java. The only difference is that they have different parameter types. They use generics and return the type T of the input parameter. How can I get rid of the duplicate code? Here are my two methods. Ultimately they both call Spring `restTemplate.exchange()` with the different types. Otherwise the methods are identical.

```
public <T> T send(Class<T> expectedClass) throws KenectRestClientException {
    if (this.logRequest) log.info("Making request: " + this.toString());

    HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<>(this.body, getTokenHeaders(this.token));
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    String compiledUrl = UrlUtils.replacePathParamsInUrl(this.url, this.pathParams, this.uriEncode) + UrlUtils.compileRequestParamsToUrl(this.requestParams, this.uriEncode);

    Object[] incompatibleStrings = extractIncompatibleStrings(compiledUrl);

    try {
        return restTemplate.exchange(compiledUrl, this.httpMethod, entity, expectedClass, incompatibleStrings).getBody();
    } catch(RestClientResponseException e) {
        log.warning(RestClientResponseException.class.getSimpleName() +
                " url: " + url +
                " status code: " + e.getRawStatusCode() +
                " error body: " + e.getResponseBodyAsString() +
                " stacktrace: " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        throw new KenectRestClientException("Failed to send request");
    } catch(ResourceAccessException e) {
        log.warning("Resource access exception " +
                " url: " + url +
                " stacktrace: " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        throw new KenectRestClientException("Failed to send request");
    }
}

public <T> T send(ParameterizedTypeReference<T> parameterizedTypeReference) throws KenectRestClientException {
    if (this.logRequest) log.info("Making request: " + this.toString());

    HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<>(this.body, getTokenHeaders(this.token));
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    String compiledUrl = UrlUtils.replacePathParamsInUrl(this.url, this.pathParams, this.uriEncode) + UrlUtils.compileRequestParamsToUrl(this.requestParams, this.uriEncode);

    Object[] incompatibleStrings = extractIncompatibleStrings(compiledUrl);

    try {
        return restTemplate.exchange(compiledUrl, this.httpMethod, entity, parameterizedTypeReference, incompatibleStrings).getBody();
    } catch(RestClientResponseException e) {
        log.warning(RestClientResponseException.class.getSimpleName() +
                " url: " + url +
                " status code: " + e.getRawStatusCode() +
                " error body: " + e.getResponseBodyAsString() +
                " stacktrace: " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        throw new KenectRestClientException("Failed to send request");
    } catch(ResourceAccessException e) {
        log.warning("Resource access exception " +
                " url: " + url +
                " stacktrace: " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        throw new KenectRestClientException("Failed to send request");
    }
}
```

Comment: Call one method from the other?

Answer (score 0):

What about passing a boolean flag, based on which you call `exchange()` passing either a `Class<T>` or a `ParameterizedTypeReference<T>`?

```
public <T> T send(T neededType, boolean flag) throws KenectRestClientException {
    if (this.logRequest) log.info("Making request: " + this.toString());

    HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<>(this.body, getTokenHeaders(this.token));
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    String compiledUrl = UrlUtils.replacePathParamsInUrl(this.url, this.pathParams, this.uriEncode) + UrlUtils.compileRequestParamsToUrl(this.requestParams, this.uriEncode);

    Object[] incompatibleStrings = extractIncompatibleStrings(compiledUrl);

    try {
        if (flag) {
            return restTemplate.exchange(compiledUrl, this.httpMethod, entity, neededType.getClass(), incompatibleStrings).getBody();
        } else {
            return restTemplate.exchange(compiledUrl, this.httpMethod, entity, ParameterizedTypeReference.forType(neededType.getClass()), incompatibleStrings).getBody();
        }

    } catch(RestClientResponseException e) {
        log.warning(RestClientResponseException.class.getSimpleName() +
                " url: " + url +
                " status code: " + e.getRawStatusCode() +
                " error body: " + e.getResponseBodyAsString() +
                " stacktrace: " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        throw new KenectRestClientException("Failed to send request");
    } catch(ResourceAccessException e) {
        log.warning("Resource access exception " +
                " url: " + url +
                " stacktrace: " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        throw new KenectRestClientException("Failed to send request");
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not going to work. There is no way for Java to infer the correct type. This is the error: incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
            ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Long>> type = send(parameterizedTypeReference, false);
                                                                     ^
    inferred: ParameterizedTypeReference<T>
    upper bound(s): ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String,Long>>,Object
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>checkedSend(ParameterizedTypeReference<T>)

Comment: Uhm. Maybe, instead of `T neededType`, we could directly use `Class<T> expectedClass` as a parameter and either pass that to `exchange(...)` or `ParameterizedTypeReference.forType(expectedClass)`, based on the flag. If this doesn't work too, or isn't suitable, then I'm sorry, I don't know what else we could try...